# Why doesn't Android cache Apple Touch Icons?

Tags: http, cache, android, favicon

I'm not sure if this applies to every Android phone, but it seems that many Android browsers don't cache the Apple Touch Icon and reload it on every page view.

I have the following in the `<head>` of my HTML pages:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/path/to/icon.jpg" />
```

In my server logs, I see many visitors from Android clients that keep requesting the icon file on every single page view:

```
[02/Jan/2014:16:21:43 +0100] "GET /path/to/icon.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 13017 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; de-de; GT-I9100 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
[02/Jan/2014:16:22:04 +0100] "GET /path/to/icon.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 13017 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; de-de; GT-I9100 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
[02/Jan/2014:16:22:30 +0100] "GET /path/to/icon.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 13017 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; de-de; GT-I9100 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
[02/Jan/2014:16:22:45 +0100] "GET /path/to/icon.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 13017 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; de-de; GT-I9100 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
[02/Jan/2014:16:23:03 +0100] "GET /path/to/icon.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 13017 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; de-de; GT-I9100 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
```

I've seen this with Android versions 4.1, 4.2, and 4.3. My server sends an `Expires` header, so caching should work fine:

```
$ date -u
Thu Jan  2 15:28:49 UTC 2014
$ curl -s -D - www.mywebsite.com/path/to/icon.jpg -o /dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 02 Jan 2014 15:28:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Last-Modified: Mon, 30 Dec 2013 14:04:44 GMT
ETag: "15201cd-316b-4eec0ecfd5700"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 12651
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Expires: Thu, 02 Jan 2014 15:43:52 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

These clients also cache CSS and other files successfully.

Has anyone seen this before? What's the reason? Is it simply an Android browser bug?